# Core Data iCloud Sync

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm experiencing problems with core data icloud syncing. I have followed WWDC 2013 videos and some other tutorials online and syncing is working for some inputs. If I add data one slowly and let the icloud sync first, it works just fine. But when I try to add a lot of data continuously in one device, only part of data records are synced to other device. But strangley, after giving it long period of time (3,4 hours may be), data are synced across devices again. My set up is as follow,

```
class CoreDataController : NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = CoreDataController()



override init(){
    super.init()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "persistentStoreWillChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "persistentStoreDidChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "recieveICloudChanges:", name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator)

}

//MARK: - Notifications Selectors

func persistentStoreWillChange (notification:NSNotification) {
    NSLog("Receive PersistentStoreWillChange Notification")

    self.managedObjectContext!.performBlock { () -> Void in
        if self.managedObjectContext!.hasChanges {
            var error:NSError? = nil
            self.managedObjectContext!.save(&error)
            if error != nil {
                println("Save error: \(error)")
            }else{
                // drop any manged object refrences
                self.managedObjectContext!.reset()
            }

        }
    }
}

func persistentStoreDidChange(notification:NSNotification)  {

    NSLog("Receive PersistentStoreDidChange Notification")
//I post notification here to let the app refresh data from other classes 
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receiveNewData", object: nil)


}


func recieveICloudChanges (notification:NSNotification){

    NSLog("Receive ICloudChanges Notification")
    self.managedObjectContext!.performBlock { () -> Void in
        self.managedObjectContext!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)

//I post notification here to let the app refresh data from other classes 
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receiveNewData", object: nil)
    }
}

//MARK: - NSManagedObjectContext Initializer 

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {


    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()


    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("cloudynote", withExtension: "momd")!
    let objectmodel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!

    managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: objectmodel)

    let documentDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).last as! NSURL

    let storeURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreData.sqlite")

    let storeOptions = [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:"CloudyNoteStore"]

    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    if managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: storeOptions, error: &error) == nil{
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }


    return managedObjectContext
    }()

}
```

Comment: Your question has your answer. Its not your fault its Apple's.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion for an alternative approach: CoreData is great for local persistent data but it's opaque nature makes it at best problematic for iCloud syncing. I gave up trying and now use CloudKit for iCloud synchronisation and retain CoreData for local persistence only. So far it appears a much better approach.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nofelmahmood/CKSIncrementalStore

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, @NofelMahmood I'll definitely try that out.

Comment: @AliBeadle, Thank you for your suggestion! Can you elaborate more about the implementation. It'd be great if you could point out some tutorials.

Comment: @NofelMahmood that is an awesome project, Thank you so much. Does it support offline data input and is there any way to retrieve syncing progress?

Comment: Thank you and No problem. Yup it does support offline data input. Actually you only input data locally which is then propagated to CloudKit Servers.  At this time you can only know when sync operation starts and finishes. btw good suggestion. I might consider adding sync progress in the next release :)

Comment: @AliBeadle check out https://medium.com/@NofelMahmood/reason-why-cloudkit-cannot-be-ignored-9c7806d76230. Its very simple to set up if you're familiar with CoreData. You just have to change the Store type to this one.. You can also open an issue for anything on github for this project and we can discuss. Happy Cloudkitting :)